# How to use service renderer with context theme?

Tags: theming, 8

I have snippet code:

```
//Load block view (have override template)
$block = Block::load('views_block_1480647185');

// get render array
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);

// get markup string
$markup = \Drupal::service('renderer')
  ->render($render);

kint($markup);
```

when i visit different **url admin** (example.com/admin/content), **non-admin** (example.com). Value markup is different.

**In example.com/admin/content**

[image: admin value]

**In example.com (use override template view)**

[image]

I think because url use different theme (bartik and seven).

So how can set **markup value** same value in url **non-admin**? How can do that with drupal service renderer?

Comment: What is the difference in markup?

Comment: @Eyal i've updated my answer.

Comment: Basically, you want to print the views results as if the theme was always betrik.

Comment: This seems like a complicated task. Can i ask why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Yes, i want user can preview block with default theme.But i can do that when call from admin theme.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `theme.manager` service to set the active theme to what you desire, render the block and set the original active theme back.

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeInitialization $theme_initialization */
$theme_initialization = \Drupal::service('theme.initialization');
$active_theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();
\Drupal::theme()->setActiveTheme($theme_initialization->getActiveThemeByName($theme));
// Render your block...
\Drupal::theme()->setActiveTheme($active_theme);
```

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Comment: I don't thinking it matters

Comment: It should, In theory 

Comment: This can be tricky, because you have to find the correct timing to change the active theme.

Comment: If you change it right back then it should work.